# c++ how to recast without lost value

Tags: c++

Anyone can help me about casting? I have 2 classes; one of them **movableObject** and other **PlantMO**. movableObject is my base class and plantMO is derived from it. First I cast a PlantMO to a movableObject for keeping all movableObject in same area. After that when I use one of them I recast it but its(PlantMO's) members' value lost.

My question is; How can I recast it without lose members?

Comment: Let me guess: You aren't using pointers or references, and are therefore experiencing object slicing?

Comment: What @chris says is probably correct. We will need to *see your code* in order to help you out. Good questions should contain a sample of code that illustrates your problem. Otherwise we will be guessing at what the actual problem is.

Comment: You can't, and you shouldn't.

Comment: Actually I used pointer. I cannot share my code because of its size. But tried it a little code block and it worked. So my way is correct, there is a mistake in my code. Thanks for answers.

Comment: @umut - when the code that's causing a problem is too big, cut it down. In order to understand a problem you have to isolate it; reducing a large program to a small one that compiles and runs and shows the problem gives you something you can post and, often, something you don't need to post because it shows you what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code I cannot show you exactly what you need to do but you need to use pointers or references, something like this (note I have not tried to compile this code, it is just an abstract example).

```
class A {
}

class B : A {
}

main () {
 B& refB = new B();
 SomeFunction(refB);
}

void SomeFunction(A& aRefToA) {
 // Call functions of A.
}
```